# Describe the graph of the function: Level Sets, Intersections

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, surfaces

Describe the graph of the function $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x, y) \rightarrow |y|$$ computing some level sets and some intersections.

I have done the following:

The level curves are defined by $$\{(x, y) \mid |y|=c\}$$

- For $c=0$ we have that $|y|=0 \Rightarrow y=0$. So, for $c=0$, the level set consists of the $x-$axis.
- For $c<0$, the level set is the empty set.

  Is this correct??

Could I improve something??

- For $c>0$ we have that $y=c, \text{ if } y>0$ and $y=-c, \text{ if } y<0$. So, of what consists the level set for $c>0$??

How can we compute the intersections??

**EDIT:**

In my book there is the following definition:

The intersection of the graph of $f$ is the intersection of the graph with a vertical plane.

For example, if we have $f(x, y)=x^2+y^2$ we have the following:

If $P_1$ is the plane $xz$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is defined by $y=0$, then the intersection of $f$ is the set $$P_1 \cap \text{ graph } f=\{(x, y, z) \mid y=0, z=x^2\}$$
that is a parabola in the plane $xz$.
Similarily, if $P_2$ is the plane $yz$, that is defined by $x=0$, then the intersection $$P_2 \cap \text{ graph } f=\{(x, y, z) \mid x=0, z=y^2\}$$ is a parabola in the plane $yz$.

So, do we take which vertical plane we want??

Comment: In my book it is $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$... It must be a typo... @aboozarshirazi

Comment: And how can we describe it?? @aboozarshirazi

Comment: I added the definition of my book at my initial post... @aboozarshirazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the diagram of this function is in $\mathbb R^3$ the  intersection with plane $xy$ is the $x$ axis and intersection with $xz$  again is $x$ axis, and the intersection with $yz$ is the set of points $(0,y,|y|)$ (similar to $\vee$!).
And the level set if $c>0$ is the tow parallel line...

Comment: What do you mean by "**tow** parallel line" ?? @aboozarshirazi

Comment: Do you mean that the level consists of the lines $y=c$ and $y=-c$ ?? Do we have to mention also at this point that $y=c$ if $>0$ and $y=-c$ if $y<0$ ?? Or is it enough to say "the level consists of the lines $y=c$ and $y=-c$" ??

Comment: Could you take a look also at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187654/level-sets-for-the-function-f? ?? @aboozarshirazi

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, the level set for a constant $c$ is the set of points $(x, y)$ such that $f(x, y) = c$. Your characterizations for $c = 0$ and $c < 0$ are totally correct.

For $c > 0$, again as you wrote, the level set is the set of all points such that $y = c$ or $y = -c$. So the level set will be the union of two parallel lines: the lines $y = c$ and the line $y = -c$.

Comment: Why is $y=c$ a plane and not a line?? @EliRose

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry: I was thinking about $\mathbb{R}^3$ since your book's definition of "intersection" is in terms of it. Fixed.

Comment: Why are the two lines perpendicular?? @EliRose

Comment: They aren't -- they're parallel. Fixed. At this point, I'd trust your own intuition, which seems pretty spot-on, over whatever I wrote :).

Comment: Ok!! :-) Are you maybe familiar with compyting intersections?? Do you know which plane we take?? @EliRose

Comment: Could you take a look also at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187654/level-sets-for-the-function-f? ?? @EliRose

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x,y)=|y|=c>0$, the level set is simply two lines, namely $f^{-1}(c)=\{(x,y)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2|y=\pm c\}$.

Comment: Do, does the level consist of the lines $y=c$ and $y=-c$ ?? Do we have to mention also at this point that $y=c$ if $>0$ and $y=-c$ if $y<0$ ?? Or is it enough to say "the level consists of the lines $y=c$ and $y=-c$" ?? @Uzman

Comment: Yes, it's enough to say $y=\pm c$.

Comment: Ok!! Are you maybe familiar with compyting intersections?? Do you know which plane we take?? @Uzman

Comment: Could you take a look also at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187654/level-sets-for-the-function-f? ?? @Uzman